# How to debug ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: php, html, debugging

I am trying to build a site which saves a (checkbox) value using PHP to a txtfile. And everything worked fine. However, I'm rearranging the files on the server in order to make it easier later to create more.

I think I rewrote the path's to the files right (including fopen(_ *DIR* _ . 'pathname')), but when I'm changing the checkbox (which is a form that submits on-click) I get a "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error and the site links to the error page of my host.

My question is, how can I debug this error? via console I can't find any errors and it's not giving me any information about missing links or files on the server.

Comment: Maybe you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code

Comment: hmm, but it worked fine before the changing of the paths. Also, im not using any while/for commands.